# BASH recursive find filename and copy to ftp

Tags: bash, find

I am working on a Bash script (see below) that recursively searches through directories on a SAN for files with a specific file name that is newer than 4 hours. Then copies all these files to a specific FTP Location and email to say the copy has been completed. The script works fine except that it only copies files on the top level directory. The error I am getting on the lower directories is this:

#

```
remote: -v
ftp: local: -v: No such file or directory
local: ./Test01/test02/folder02_01_1200_m30.mp4 remote: ./Test01/test02/folder02_01_1200_m30.mp4
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||45127|)
550 ./Test01/test02/folder02_01_1200_m30.mp4: File does not exist. (2)
221 Goodbye.
```

#

Here is the Script

```
#!/bin/bash
#The location from where the script should search
GSPORIGIN='/Volumes/folder01/folder02'

#File Names to be moved
FILE1='*1200_m30.mp4'

#FTP Details
HOST='xxxx.upload.com'
USER='xxxxxxx'
PASSWD='xxxxxxxxxxxx'
#the destination directory on the FTP
DESTDIR="/8619/_!/TEST"


# Go to the location from where the search should start 
cd $GSPORIGIN
for file in `find . -type f -name "*1200_m30.mp4" -mmin -240`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd $DESTDIR
mput -v $file
EOT
echo "$file has been copied to FTP" | mail -s "$file has been copied to FTP in Directory $DESTDIR"  xxx.xxx@xxx.com; 
else exit 1
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you're doing, you'll have to recreate the directories on the destination FTP. 
use the basename/dirname commmands and a mkdir command like this :

```
for file in `find . -type f -name "*1200_m30.mp4" -mmin -240`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then

destdirname=`dirname "$file"`

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd $DESTDIR
mkdir $destdirname 
mput -v $file
EOT
echo "$file has been copied to FTP" | mail -s "$file has been copied to FTP in Directory $DESTDIR"  xxx.xxx@xxx.com; 
else exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - one thing when I run the script it creates the directories but it fails to move the files: ./Test_1200_m30.mp4
Trying 96.7.36.11...
Connected to ftp.xxxxxxxxx.net.
220 Content Storage FTP Server
530 Please login with USER and PASS
331 Password required for XXXXX.
230 User stor_admin logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
Interactive mode off.
250 CWD command successful.
550 .: Forbidden filename (4)
250 CWD command successful.
usage: put local-file [remote-file]
221 Goodbye.
./Test_1200_m30.mp4

Comment: The fix is mput -v $file $filename

Comment: @JRM : fine, I wasn't sure of the `mput` syntax, I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you - just tried your suggestion to remove the cd $destdirname and it works - anyway thank you it works a treat!!

Answer (score 2):

To copy multiple files in nested directories: I would suggest you to look at [rsync utility](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=unix%20rsync&fp=1&cad=b) to do this job for you.

rsync will create all the remote directories whenever needed and it will keep files completely in sync even after frequent runs.